# How i can print a pdf

Tags: java

I want to print a pdf but all solution i have tried doesn't work.

I want print the pdf with the pop up where u can choose your printer.

When i try the solution of other people this is often by silent printing.

i try this :

```
 DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.SERVICE_FORMATTED.PAGEABLE;
PrintRequestAttributeSet patts = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
patts.add(Sides.DUPLEX);
PrintService[] ps = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(flavor, patts);
if (ps.length == 0) {
    throw new IllegalStateException("No Printer found");
}
System.out.println("Available printers: " + Arrays.asList(ps));

PrintService myService = null;
for (PrintService printService : ps) {
    if (printService.getName().equals("HP Deskjet 3070 B611 series")) {
        myService = printService;
        break;
    }
}


FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(path_doss);
Doc pdfDoc = new SimpleDoc(fis, DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE, null);
DocPrintJob printJob = myService.createPrintJob();
printJob.print(pdfDoc, new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet());
fis.close();
```

this

```
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(path_doss);

Doc pdfDoc = new SimpleDoc(fis, null, null);

DocPrintJob printJob = printService.createPrintJob();

printJob.print(pdfDoc, new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet());

fis.close();
```

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of Scanner for interaction with user.

```
System.out.print("Please select one of the printers numbers: 1. Printer1,  2.Printer2 etc");
 Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
 String sentence = scanner.nextLine();
```

And then use that input to select the printer from ur list and print.

Answer (score 0):

Use [ServiceUI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/print/ServiceUI.html) to show a print selection dialog.

If you have an existing window (such as a JFrame), you should use it to determine the first three arguments.  The fourth and fifth arguments come from the PrintServiceLookup call.

So a typical invocation might look like this:

```
PrintService defaultService = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();
if (defaultService == null) {
    defaultService = ps[0];
    for (PrintService printService : ps) {
        if (printService.getName().equals("HP Deskjet 3070 B611 series")) {
            defaultService = printService;
            break;
        }
    }
}

PrintService myService = ServiceUI.printDialog(
    mainWindow.getGraphicsConfiguration(),
    mainWindow.getX() + 40,
    mainWindow.getY() + 40,
    ps, defaultService, flavor, patts);

if (myService == null) {
    System.out.println("User canceled print operation.");
    return;
}
```

If you don't have an application window, you can pass null for the first argument.  There is no (easy) way to know the size of the print dialog, so for the second and third arguments, you'll have to guess.  For example:

```
Point center = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getCenterPoint();

PrintService myService = ServiceUI.printDialog(
    null, center.x - 200, center.y - 200,
    ps, defaultService, flavor, patts);
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you try this, this will open up the file which you wanted to print and then you may choose to print it by selecting a printer.

```
Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("c:/test.pdf"));
```

Comment: I want print it by the program not by the user.

Comment: You can make use of Scanner to ge the input from the user